# Saving Inputs to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, save

So I am making a project and I want to create a new clinic.

On my UI we insert all the topics that we need to create the clinic and they must be saved as ArrayList and I am struggling with this method.

this is how i am asking for the input, should i change to a scanner?

```
laboratoryId = Utils.readLineFromConsole("Enter Clinic Id: ");
```

class to the array

```
public class ClinicalAnalysisLabStore{

        private ArrayList<ClinicalAnalysisLab> cliniclist;
        
        public ClinicalAnalysisLabStore(){
                cliniclist = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public ArrayList<ClinicalAnalysisLab> getCliniclist() {
                return cliniclist;
        }
```

```
      cals = new ClinicalAnalysisLabStore();
        ArrayList<ClinicalAnalysisLab> cliniclist = cals.getCliniclist();
```

```
for(ClinicalAnalysisLab cals : cliniclist){
                    System.out.print(cals.getLaboratoryId()+"\n");
                    System.out.print(cals.getName()+ "\n");
                    System.out.print(cals.getAddress()+"\n");
                    System.out.print(cals.getPhoneNumber()+"\n");
                    System.out.print(cals.getTinNumber()+"\n");
                    System.out.print(cals.getTestType()+"\n");

                }
                Utils.readLineFromConsole("The Operation was a success!");
```

this is a short cut from my code where i am trying to print the arraylist but it only prints "The Operation was a success!"

Comment: Where did you add variables to the arraylist?

Comment: public class ClinicalAnalysisLabStore{

private ArrayList<ClinicalAnalysisLab> cliniclist;

public ClinicalAnalysisLabStore(){

                cliniclist = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public ArrayList<ClinicalAnalysisLab> getCliniclist() {

                return cliniclist;
        }


this is the class where i made the array

Comment: Although you made the arraylist, you never added any items to it, so the arraylist is empty.

Comment: so how do i add items to it?

Comment: See my answer posted below

Comment: and so this should be replaced on my 1st or 2nd code?

Comment: It doesn't replace anything. What you're doing is creating a new object. So, put this right below the "laboratoryId" code. Also, attach your code for the "ClinicalAnalysisLab" class

Comment: posted it bellow

Comment: So now the problem that i am facing is that i need to initialize my variables i can't find a way to make set work

Comment: That's right. I edited my post with an example.

Comment: Did the code work?

Comment: but it is not supposed to initialize tha variables so thats my concern right now

Comment: it is but its not getting the input, only the initialize ones and it does not change

Comment: If you don't want to initialize the variables yourselves, all you have to do is get the input multiple times. Repeat this: laboratoryId = Utils.readLineFromConsole("Enter Clinic Id: "); for all the different variables

Comment: and i have that, check my post with RegistClinicalAnalysisLabUI

Comment: Then, what's the problem?

Comment: already was abble to made it, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. If my answer worked, you can check if below.

Answer (score 1):

You're ArrayList is empty. So, the code is actually working perfectly.

What you'll need to do is add items to the ArrayList.

To add an item:

```
laboratoryId = Utils.readLineFromConsole("Enter Clinic Id: ");
ClinicalAnalysisLab obj = new ClinicalAnalysisLab(laboratoryId, *name*, *address*, *phoneNumber*, *tinNumber*) {
clinicList.add(obj);
```

In this case, you would just create the object based on however you want. So, change the variables "name", "address", "phoneNumber", and "tinNumber" with whatever you want.

One example would be:

```
laboratoryId = Utils.readLineFromConsole("Enter Clinic Id: ");
ClinicalAnalysisLab obj = new ClinicalAnalysisLab(laboratoryId, "First Lab", "32 Lincoln Rd", "666 666 6666, "102") {
clinicList.add(obj);
```